# Cloud functions, create document if there is no document else send error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a system where if the user request a coupon

- It will check if the user have already requested a coupon
- Then it should be in a collection as a document.
- If there is no document it will generate a document.

So what I expect is if I run the code and there is a document in the collection it should cancel the operation? 
But it doesn't. It just updates the documents fields createdAt and qrCodeId.

```
export const addCoupon = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const key = nanoid();
  const today = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  const uid = context.auth!.uid;
  const couponRef = db
    .collection("kuponger")
    .doc("newCoupons")
    .collection(data.school)
    .doc(uid);
  const doc = await couponRef.get();

  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-precondition",
      "Du måste vara inloggad"
    );
  }

  if (!doc.exists) {
    couponRef
      .set({
        createdAt: today,
        createdBy: uid,
        qrCodeId: key,
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", error);
      });
  } else {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("already-exists", "finns redan");
  }
});
```

It looks like it should work, but when I try to run it and a document is already present in the collection, it will update the document and not cancel the operation.

Could you please help me?

If you need more information please comment.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
const uid = context.auth!.uid;
```

You want to use:

```
const uid = context.auth?.uid;
```

to accomplish optional chaining.  However, I think it would be better to move the "precondition code" *first*, in which case the optional chaining should not be necessary.

```
export const addCoupon = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-precondition",
      "Du måste vara inloggad"
    );
  }

  const key = nanoid();
  const today = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  const uid = context.auth.uid;
  const couponRef = db
    .collection("kuponger")
    .doc("newCoupons")
    .collection(data.school)
    .doc(uid);
  const doc = await couponRef.get();

  if (!doc.exists) {
    couponRef
      .set({
        createdAt: today,
        createdBy: uid,
        qrCodeId: key,
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", error);
      });
  } else {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("already-exists", "finns redan");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it stills updates the document even when it shouldn't.. You have any idea how this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by reinstalling firebase function and reinitializing it all again.